# Why doesn't Dart DevTools' Network page show a Response?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, dart-devtools

I'm making a simple call to `http://postman-echo.com/get?foo=bar` but the Response tab of Dart Devtools' Network page doesn't show anything.  Is this a bug or is there something that I need to do to make it show the results by default?

Here is the code I'm running to make the request:

```dart
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('http://postman-echo.com/get?foo=bar'));

request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
```

[image: Network page screenshot]

Comment: if you're making the request with code, can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2860#issuecomment-1381885447